# Tensorflow memory issue

Tags: memory-management, tensorflow

I have a problem with tensorflow. 
I need to create several model (e.g. neural networks), but after the computation of the parameters of such models, I will create new models, and I won't need the previous models anymore. 
Seems that tensorflow is not able to recognize which model I am still using, and which ones are without reference anymore, and I don't know in which way should I delete the previous models. As result the memory keep increasing its size, until the system kills my execution, which, obviously, is something that I would like to avoid. 
How do you think I should deal with this problem? What's the correct way to 'delete' the previous models?

thanks in advance,
Samuele

Comment: Could you be a little more concrete in what you mean by "recognizing which model you're using". How are you defining models? For example, if you [close the `Session`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Session#close) used to compute the parameters and reset the graph, you should not be holding on to any state.

Comment: Hi ash, thanks for your reply. The problem with closing the session, is that I need still to create new models (and new optimizers) after, and therefore i need to initialize again the variables. The solution that I've adopted to solve the problem, is to instantiate any time I need a new model and a new session on its model, in the way that the old graph is unreferenced. this solution seems to solve the "memory issue", but still I think is not very clean. I would like to better what is the correct way on using graphs and sessions. At the moment I haven't been able to understand it.